# MS Word элементы управления

Tags: ms-word

Как на печати скрыть не заполненные элементы управления? Допустим есть таблица в ней 4 строки, заполнено только 2. На печати выходит 2 заполненные строки плюс не заполненные. Т.е. выглядит это так

[image: Таблица]